# As páginas não são renderizadas por meio do React Router Dom

Tags: javascript, react, react-router

Sou recente na programação, instalei a biblioteca react-router-dom para trocar uma página quando clica ou trocar o link de "/" por "/usuarios", aparentemente o código parece estar certo, não nada de errado no item `routes.js`, importei as pages que estão nos `containers`, mas não renderiza, quando coloco o index Home ou Users importados no lugar no `<Routes />`, vai de boa no
`const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')); root.render(<><Routes /> <GlobalStyle /></> );`, mas deixando assim como tá, não é ''ativada'' a biblioteca.

De forma bem objetiva e sucinta, a página não renderiza, fica tudo branco. Qual é o b.o dessa biblioteca? Sei que recentemente passou por uma atualização, mas aparentemente esta certo

Código do arquivo **Routes**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './containers/Home'
import Users from './containers/Users';

function MyRoutes() {
    
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={Home}></Route>
            <Route path="/usuarios" element={Users}></Route>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
        
    )
};

export default MyRoutes;
```

Código do **index.js renderizador**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import Routes from './routes'
import GlobalStyle from './styles/globalStyle';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <>
        <Routes /> <GlobalStyle />
    </>
);
```

Answer (score -1):

É suposto colocares os elementos nas rotas em formato de tag.

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home/>}></Route>
<Route path="/usuarios" element={<Users/>}></Route>
```